# The resulting values are not what they indicate?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, basin

I am using ArcMap 10.3.

When I create a watershed, using the Watershed tool in the Hydrology tool set, I am receiving values that should really be representing the number of water splitting lines, correct ?

However, I did not receive those results, what does the value I'm receiving then indicate?

Here is the resulting graph:

[image: whatersade for basin yarmuk]

here is the tool set I'm working with:

[image]

Comment: What were the precise steps that you performed to produce that graph?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm Arabian and my English is not good:(

Comment: This chart of Yarmouk Basin in Jordan when you did watersade

Comment: The watershed command simply gives you the values of the points used to create the watershed. Typically an ID like 1, 2, 3 just to indicate which point was used to create the watershed.

Comment: Your question is unclear of what exactly you want to do? Could you give us more details?